# What's the best pattern to log activity?

Tags: objective-c, design-patterns, logging

I write my application (obj-c) and i have created a very rigid class hierarchy.
Every class know less or nothing about others class and how those class manage their data.

Now i need create a log file with a full description of the activity, but because none class know the "full" process, none class can write a "full" log.

I'm looking for a design patter or best practice to share information among classes without sharing lot of details.

I hope my english was understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think knowing each class about others may not be good practice for you. In that way, your classes will become more and more dependent each other, which contradicts of the many design principles and breaks the modularity of your code.

I would add another module for your log activity, giving the ability of knowing about all the process, will give you the power about logging. This method is easy and simple enough to implement. Moreover, you can take a look at [Aspect Oriented Architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_software_development) and [Aspect-oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming), which gives you to power of seperating the corss cutting concerns(logs in your case). you should check [AspectCocoa](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/AspectCocoa) and [AOP-in-Objective-C](https://github.com/moszi/AOP-in-Objective-C)

Answer (score 0):

Some patterns where implemented in Log4Net (http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/features.html)

**Hierarchical logging architecture**
Hierarchical logging is an ideal fit with component based development. Each component has its own of logger. When individually tested, the properties of these loggers may be set as the developer requires. When combined with other components, the loggers inherit the properties determined by the integrator of the components. One can selectively elevate logging priorities on one component without affecting the other components. This is useful when you need a detailed trace from just a single component without crowding the trace file with messages from other components. All this can be done through configuration files; no code changes are required.

**Logging Context**
log4net can be used to collect logging context data in a way that is transparent to the developer at the point of logging. The GlobalContext and the ThreadContext allow the application to store contextual data that is attached to logging messages. For instance, in a web service, once the caller is authenticated the username of the caller could be stored in a ThreadContext property. This property would then be automatically logged as part of each subsequent logging message made from the same thread.

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping each class with a logging decorator?